# comprehension list with list of filters python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, compression, list-comprehension

Is there a way to filter a list like this?

```
movies = [
   [["t", "transformers"],["g", "animation"],["d", "2005"]],
   [["t", "ted"],["g", "comedy"],["d", "2008"]],
   [["t", "starwars"],["g", "action"],["d", "2000"]]
]
```

having a filter list like this

```
filter = [["g", "animation"], ["d", "2005"]]
```

and receive

```
["transformers"]
```

I think is not possible due to the structure of the movies list, but I don't know if a Python wizard  maybe have an answer.

thank you if you have a suggestion about this.

Comment: i would start by restructuring the movies list to have a list of dicts

Comment: Or use a `NamedTuple` since it looks like the fields are regular.

Comment: Sure, you could do a membership check for each filter over the entire list of movies.  Of course, that will be painfully slow for a list of any significant size.  You should probably be writing this in to a DB, then querying in to that, as it will be faster.

Comment: Yeah, all what you say is correct but is about this concrete problem... thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
movies = [
   [["t", "transformers"],["g", "animation"],["d", "2005"]],
   [["t", "ted"],["g", "comedy"],["d", "2008"]],
   [["t", "starwars"],["g", "action"],["d", "2000"]]
]

fil = [["g", "animation"], ["d", "2005"]]


print [i[0][1] for i in movies if fil[0] in i and fil[1] in i]
```

this will print:

```
['transformers']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Object Oriented Programming (OPP). You can implement a very simple class that will save you a lot of work after.

```
class Movie:

    def __init__(self, title, genre, year):
        self.title = title
        self.genre = genre
        self.year = year


    def filter(self, filter_):
        """ filter_ here is a dict."""
        for feature, value in filter_.items():
            if getattr(self, feature) != value:
                return False
        return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title


movies = [
    Movie("transformers", "animation", 2005),
    Movie("ted", "comedy", 2008),
    Movie("starwars", "action", 2000)
]

filter_ = { "genre": "animation", "year": 2005}

movies = [movie for movie in movies if movie.filter(filter_)]

print(movies)
```

this produce the ouput:

```
['transformers']
```

And also you can do things like:

```
print(movies[0].title)
```

that will produce the ouput:

```
'transformers'
```

Comment: *Aside*: I think you mean [**genre**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genre), not [**gender**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gender).

Comment: I believe you should have `genre` variable replace `feature` inside the `if` statement of the `filter` function. 
Otherwise, where else do you compare the `value` of the `feature` key in the `filter_` dictionary with the `genre` parameter of the `Movie` object?

Answer (score 0):

First step, restructure in dicts (I renamed `filter` to `filtr`, since `filter` is a built-in function):

```
movies = [dict(item) for item in movies]
filtr = dict(filtr)
```

Then, filter according to your criterion:

```
filtered = [item for item in movies if all(item[k] == v for k,v in filtr.iteritems())]
```

Here, you loop on all movies, and you look for those that match all the filter elements.

Then, you print all the matching titles

```
print [item['t'] for item in filtered]
# ['transformers']
```